# Darken Angular Material Dark theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to darken the default Angular Material Dark theme but am not sure how to do so. I'd like the background of my app to be #010101 and cards/other UI elements a lighter color (preferably #171717).

As far as I know, changing the primary/accent color of the theme won't help. This is what I have so far:

```
$primary: mat-palette($mat-red);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-red, A200, A100, A400);

$theme: mat-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent
  )
));

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

How do I do this?